# Visualforce <ol><li>

Tags: visualforce, css, html

I am creating a WORD document from Visualforce. I am having an Issue with Spacing between Numbers using the "ol li" it is like adding an extra page break or something. Any Advice.

```
      <ol>       
        <li>
         List of owners who have 50% or more ownership interest - 
       </li>
      <br/>
       <li>
        The intended End Use 
       </li>
```

It is coming out like this:

```
 1. List of owners who have 50% or more ownership interest - 


 2. The intended End Use
```

where it should be coming out like this:

```
 1. List of owners who have 50% or more ownership interest - 

 2. The intended End Use
```

Answer (score 2):

1. You don't need a line break between list item tags. You can remove `<br/>`, which is likely part of the issue.
2. You're not really generating a Word doc. You're generating an HTML document which Word is in some circumstances willing to *pretend* is a Word doc and render. Because of this your ability to control how the document renders and is formatted is both limited and highly specific to the details of Word's rendering engine.

If you need fine control over the rendered output, you will likely have better results using a dedicated document generation solution that understands real Word documents.

Comment: You are correct the <br/> is causing the issue however if that was not there, there would be no space at all which i indeed want a space just not 2 spaces

Answer (score 0):

This is old but anyway... you need to use CSS to add a padding on bottom of li elements.

```
<style> li { padding-bottom: 10px; } </style>
```

Comment: can you please provide details and an example of the code for your answer?

Comment: <style> li {  padding-bottom: 10px;  } </style>